# Jquery not working with ionic2?I have jquery folder in src folder

Tags: jquery, ionic2

It is a part of ionic2 app files.This is my html file.I want to merge jquery with ionic2 datetime to disable past(invalid ) dates......On serving it shows blank ...whereas without jquery rest content is displayed.

```
       <ion-header>
          <ion-navbar>
          </ion-navbar>
           <button ion-button menuToggle>
             <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
           </button>
           <ion-title>c1</ion-title>

         <link href = "jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.2/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

          <script >
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#calendar").datepicker({
                minDate : -0 ,
                maxDate : "1y" 
              });
            });
          </script>


        </ion-header>
```

Comment: The path is wrong. Don't forget your main.js is in the ./www folder. This is where the script is executed.

Comment: We are working with ionic2.....where sould i put the folder containiig js and css files? @misha130